# How do I get rid of this pop up when I try to select text?

Tags: mac, google-chrome, trackpad

I'm not sure if this is a macbook issue (My sister gave me a macbook with OS 10.9.1) or a google chrome issue.

When I'm using Google Chrome and want to select text (either by tapping three times over a word in a phrase, by double clicking then dragging, or by 3-finger dragging over a phrase) this pop up pops up over my screen with the words I selected showing up 1 by 1. It goes away when I click. But it's really annoying.

[image]

What is the point of it and how do I get rid of it???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like you have a Chrome plug-in that is a web site reader.

On your screen shot one can see the "250wpm" (words per minute)in bottom right corner, that would be an indication that you have a reader plug installed.

Remove it or fix it.